# Can I remove Source Object from all sub forms when closing main form?

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I am trying to loop through all the controls on a form that have a tag property of "Page". These particular controls are actually sub forms on a Tab Control on the main form. I do not set the Source Object of these sub forms until the tab is clicked by the user. I want to do a routine to remove all of the Source Objects of these sub form when the main form is closed. This is what I have tried, but it doesn't remove the actual Source Object:

```
Private Sub TestTag()
Dim c As Control    

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If c.Tag = "Page" Then
        Debug.Print c.Name
        c.SourceObject = ""
    End If
Next c    
End Sub
```

Comment: This should not be necessary. If SourceObject property is not set in design then it will still not be set when form closes. Setting SourceObject property in run-time does not change the saved property setting.